# How to put the limit for numeric textbox in kendogrid column filter menu?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendonumerictextbox

Here issue is in the kendogrid column menu filter is not having limit to filter i don't need the negative value  .In second image while enter the arrow it's going negativeve values 
how to restrict the negative value?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [filterMenuInit](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-filterMenuInit) event of the grid. Then find the numeric textbox and set its min value to 0 using the [min](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/numerictextbox#methods-min) method. Here is a sample implementation:

```html
  <div id="grid"></div>
  <script>
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource:{ 
      data: [ 
        { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
        { name: "Jane Doe", age: 33 }      
      ],
      schema: {
        model: {
          fields: {
            age: { type: "number" }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    filterable: {
      extra: false
    },
    filterMenuInit: function(e) {
      var numeric = e.container.find("[data-role=numerictextbox]").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
      if (numeric) {
        numeric.min(0);
      }
    }
  });
  </script>
```

And a live demo: http://jsbin.com/itiwos/1/edit

Comment: thank you for reply my version 2012 with licensed ,is it not working in old version(2012)?

Comment: Indeed, the filterMenuInit event was introduced in the Q1 2013 release.

Comment: Is it possible to use 2012 version using any other event.

Comment: ok thank you one more is we have different columns with different ranges(0.7,123,5555,67 like this) but i also need to apply max value, so please can you tell me to how to apply the different max value for different columns?

Comment: You can put the title of the column in the jquery selector: $("#grid th:contains(age) .k-grid-filter")

http://jsbin.com/itiwos/3/edit